# Switch statement not being entered

Tags: java, for-loop, switch-statement

I'm experiencing a strange problem. I have a case statement, and it is not being entered, at all. I've stepped it through with the Eclipse debugger and it gets the line above and then goes straight to the line after. It compiles and runs with no errors.

This is a general outline:

```
    for (int k = 0; k<9; k++) {
        System.out.println("Program is here - #1");
        doSomething();
        switch (switchcode) {

        case 1:
            switch (k) {

            case 1: case 2: case 3:
                doOneOneTwoThree(); //#2
                break;
            case 4: case 5: case 6:
                doOneFourFiveSix(); //#3
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("error k defaulted in case 1");
                break;
            }
            break;
        case 2:
            switch (k) {

            case 1: case 2: case 3:
                doTwoOneTwoThree(); //#4
                break;
            case 4: case 5: case 6:
                doTwoFourFiveSix(); //#5
                break;
            default:
                System.err.println("error k defaulted in case 2");
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            System.err.println("error switchcode defaulted");
            break;
        }

        doSomethingElse();
    }
```

I'm doing something wrong, no doubt, but I really don't know what exactly.
Is it because I am switching on k within a case? I have done this before and it has worked, perhaps luckily.

Is the nesting of case statements within a larger for-loop causing problems?

I saw "Branch Prediction Fail" occasionally whilst I was researching around, I don't know exactly what that is but it might be happening.

Is having `break;` in the default cases causing problems? I don't think it is because I tried it without them and had the same results.

Sorry for the long code and question. Thanks for ANY guidance.

Comment: Please try to refactor this into a short but *complete* program which demonstrates the problem.

Comment: What is the value of `switchcode`?

Comment: Are you sure that 'doSomething()' does not throw an exception? This is unrelated to branch prediction failure...

Comment: What value of "switchcode" do you see when you debug?

Comment: Try to rewrite the program as a minimal test case. Remove as much code as possible.

Comment: I'm not sure what I could edit out and still demonstrate my code, I did apologise for that. doSomething() runs as it is meant to, the debugger goes through it with no problems. Switchcode can be 1 or 2, if not producing an error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If Eclipse doesn't hit a line it should, then the source might be out-of-sync with the code compiled by Eclipse.

Try to do a clean & new build.

Restarting Eclipse or reimporting the project might also help.

Answer (score 2):

The most likely explanation is that you are not debugging the compiled code you think you are.  What you can see when you are running slightly old classes with new source is that the source will be correct and up to date, but the compiled code will skip to old line numbers which can look sort of right.

I would try to do as clean a build as you can.  If that doesn't work try moving the code around. e.g. adding lots of blank lines.